# iOS 10 Safari JavaScript setting disabled

Tags: safari, javascript, ios

Today, JavaScript in Safari suddenly stopped functioning. I had just updated my iPhone 6s to iOS 10 yesterday. I eventually noticed that somehow, JavaScript had been disabled in the Safari settings. Furthermore, the control itself is disabled!

[image]

Why might javascript be permanently disabled? How can I re-enable it?

It obviously makes it difficult to debug javascript when it's disabled on my debug device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered mine had this issue due to my corporate email app restricting JavaScript on safari, post update

Comment: This seems to have been it - polling around the office, those with the device management software installed and who are on iOS 10 have the same issue. I suspect the iOS 10 update caused the issue. Taking it up with IT. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following is based on my observation.

By default the Safari JavaScript is enabled, because most of the website that I visited that extensively using JavaScript are working in Safari. The problem starts only when I `Clear History and Website Data` and go to `Settings > Safari > Advanced`.

I think as soon as you hit `Advanced` "for the first time" the program just has an issue as no previous settings are set, thus setting itself to `Disable`.

I exited from settings and visit the previous website that are using JavaScript, obviously all of them either don't show up or become a Dumb website except you click a link that uses anchor.

Solution: Just go to `Advanced` again and set `Enable` the JavaScript setting. Next time you visit this remain enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, iOS 10 on a 6s, my JavaScript control was greyed out, but was stuck in the on position. However, JavaScript was not working, the browser was acting just as if java was off. 
I did absolutely nothing, looked at it last night right before I went to sleep. This morning, I opened safari, noticed that google searches loooked different, checked the setting again and it is no longer greyed out, and JavaScript is now enabled and working fine.
I didn't do anything to make this happen. No power cycles, sw updates, nothing. 
Very confusing