# JavaScript working when disabled (factory settings) in iOS is a bug?

Tags: ios, safari, development, mobile-safari

I have noticed all my iOS devices and my those of my friends have JavaScript disabled in Safari settings by default (Settings > Safari > Advanced). Yet, JavaScript seemed to be working on all websites.

[image]

When I turned it on, websites continued working as expected. But when I turned it back off most websites didn't work correctly because, you know, JavaScript is essential to them. My question is, why was it turned off by default and still working? I have iOS 11 and there's a similar question with iOS 10 here: [iOS 10 Safari JavaScript setting disabled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252904/ios-10-safari-javascript-setting-disabled). Is this a bug or is there a reason for this?

Comment: Probably one of those random, annoying, iOS 11 bugs :(

Comment: I've seen this also. It is visibly disabled but demonstrably ENabled... but only if you've never altered it before. It's definitely confusing, because it makes me wonder if by default there are a certain number of JavaScript functions enabled and no more, but that after you toggle it on it is somehow enabling more things than were necessary by default, and there's no way to get back to the _actual_ default, because we can't even be sure based on the controls what that actually was.

Answer (score 1):

"*My question is, why was it turned off by default and still working?*"

Obviously it was not turned off. The better question is: why was it displaying as disabled when it clearly was not? The only answer is that it is a mistake (regardless as to whether it was intended or not, which let's hope for everyone's sake it was not).

"*Is this a bug or is there a reason for this?*"

It's a bug whether there's a reason or not.

I've sent this information along as a 'Bug report' to Apple via both...
https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html
...and also...
https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html

If this bothers you, I suggest you do the same.